# Identifying days based on date values in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have dates along with time under Col K and certain values (numbers) corresponding to these days under Col M.

I have a code that changes the color of these values if they are greater than 1 and if they have a text "waiting" in col P.

What I don't know to do is, add the below condition into this code:

1.I want to identify if these days belongs to a Sunday.

2.If Yes, then I want to check if the Sunday hours (lets say the date/time format is "15/1/2016 17:00" so the remaining time left for Sunday to get over is 0.3 day) subtracted from the number in Col M and if still the number is >1, then it should be highlighted in "Red".

3.The subtraction should not affect or appear in the current sheet.

I tried the below code but I'm not sure where I'm making the mistake as there are no result.

```
Sub Datefilter()
Dim r As Long
Dim m As Long

On Error GoTo ExitHere:
m = Range("M:P").Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   For r = 1 To m
      remainingDay = 0

       If Weekday(Range("K" & r)) = 1 Then

              remainingDay = Round((24 - Format(TimeValue(Range("K" & r)), "h")) / 24, 1)

               End If
      If Range("P" & r) = "*waiting*" Then
            If Range("M" & r) - remainingDay >= 1 Then
                  Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 3
                  Else
                 Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 0
               End If
               End If
      Next r
      ExitHere:
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Try to comment out the `On Error GoTo ExitHere` and see if it shows any errors

Comment: It shows type mismatch error in `If Weekday(Range("K" & r)) = 1 Then`

Comment: What's the content of `Range("K" & r)` at the moment of the type mismatch? Excel is probably not being able to convert it as a `Date`. Try to specifically get the `.Value` property -> `Range("K" & r).Value` and see if it works

Comment: Where do I include `Range("K" & r).Value` in the code?

Comment: Replace `If Weekday(Range("K" & r)) = 1 Then` with `If Weekday(Range("K" & r).Value) = 1 Then`

Comment: Still getting the same error at the same place

Comment: And what's the content of `Range("K" & r).Value`?

Comment: These are dates in "MM/DD/YYY TIME" format, example - 1/15/2016 21:16

Comment: Not what I'm asking. If you type `? Range("K" & r).Value` in the immediate window, does it display exactly `1/15/2016 21:16`? If the cell in question is empty or does not contain a date value, Excel will not be able to parse it to `Weekday`, hence the `Type mismatch`

Comment: I changed `For r = 1 To m` to `For r = 2 To m` as the vales start from row 2 and the type mismatch error was not coming anymore..But neither is the result. After changing this, I tried the immediate window and type what you said and got error as `Run time error 1004 - Application-defined or object-defined error`

Comment: The script should be running for it to work. Put a breakpoint in row `If Weekday(Range("K" & r)) = 1 Then` (click on the row and press `F9`), then run your script. The script will stop on that row, highlighting it in yellow. When that happens, type `? Range("K" & r).Value` in the immediate window and press `Enter`

Comment: The immediate window gives this answer `1/15/2016 9:16:18 PM`

Comment: Keep running it row by row with `F8` and checking for any anomalies or mistakes. See if it completes the execution with no errors and correctly following the flow as you intended. You can enable the Locals window (click in View -> Locals Window from the top menu) and check each variable as the code goes to make sure the variables are being populated with expected values. (btw, 1/15/2016 was a friday, so it won't enter your `If` in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Datefilter()

Dim r, lastrow, remainingDay As Long

'On Error GoTo ExitHere: ' I recommend to delete this

lastrow = Range("M:P").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   For r = 1 To lastrow
      remainingDay = 0

        If Weekday(Range("K" & r).Value, vbSunday) = 1 Then
                remainingDay = Round((24 - Format(TimeValue(Range("K" & r)), "h")) / 24, 1)

             If InStr(1, Range("P" & r).Text, "waiting", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

                 If Range("M" & r) - remainingDay >= 1 Then
                     Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 3
                 Else
                     Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 0
                 End If
             End If
        End If
    Next r
'ExitHere: ' I recommend to delete this
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: type mismatch in `If Weekday(Range("K" & r).Value, vbSunday) = 1 Then`

Comment: What data do you have in the column "K"? it should be date/time as OP stated. The `Weekday` should work with this kind of input and return a number.

Comment: These are dates in "MM/DD/YYY TIME" format, example - 1/15/2016 21:16

Comment: I have checked this code with these inputs: "1/22/2017 21:16"
 (Sunday), "1/15/2016 21:16" (Friday) and it recognizes the days correctly..

Answer (score 4):

I feel this would be much easier with Excel's built-in functions and some helper columns.

(1) Use the `WEEKDAY()` function to get the day of the week. Then use a simple comparison to check if it is Sunday.

(2) Dates are stored as the amount of time expired since 0th January 1900, with partial dates as fractions. Therefore, to return the time, simply take the rounded bit of the date from the date: `=A1-ROUNDDOWN(A1,0)`

(3) Use conditional formatting to check if the cell is < 1 and then turn it red.

Let me know if you would like a screenshot of an example.

Comment: thanks for the insight..But I need to accomplish this is VBA code :(

Comment: Ok, but why does it have to be VBA? It will be faster and easier in Excel. And you get all of the benefits such as being able to use undo, seeing the calculation steps etc.

Comment: Try using the `weekday` in code: `WhatDayisIt = Weekday("15/1/2017", vbMonday)`. It will show you which day is it  (i this case 7 as i have set Monday as 1 day of week) .

Comment: This code is part of a larger code that is VBA, so I'm trying to create a VBA code for this. I ahve edited OP with modified code..still this doesn't work

Comment: It's fine being part of a larger code...but I would still use Excel. I've looked at your profile and the other question you asked about colouring cells and I would similarly approach that with Excel. This makes me doubt that your entire solution *has* to be in VBA! Seriously, Excel is better - you can use undo, it will update automatically, it will handle you inserting columns, it will show you the calculation steps, you don't need to enable macros...